# How to express "there exist a number of something such that ..." in the language of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In multivariate real analysis, differentiability is defined as follows:

> A function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ if and only if $x_{0}$ is in the interior of the domain of $f$ and there exist $n$ constants $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, $\dots$, $m_{n}$ such that
> \begin{equation}
> \lim_{x\to x_{0}}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}\left(x_{i}-{x_{0,i}}\right)}{\lVert x-x_{0} \rVert} = 0,
> \end{equation}
> where $x = \left(x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}\right)$ and $x_{0} = \left(x_{0,1},x_{0,2},\dots,x_{0,n}\right)$.

I have no problem with understanding this definition. However, this definition reminded me of one question: how to express "there exist a number of objects such that" in the language of set theory? It seems that the set of natural numbers has to play a role in the expression, but I am not sure how to construct such a proposition rigorously, especially when the universal quantification on $n$ is needed.

Comment: $$\exists m \in \mathbb{R}^n :\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0) - m^{\top}\cdot(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||}=0\right)$$

Comment: But $n$ is fixed in this context, so what hinders you to say something like $\forall x_1, ..., x_n$? In a more concrete case you can always introduce variables $\forall x,y,z$, so you might as well call them $\forall x_1, x_2, x_3$ to save $y,z$ to denote other things. 1,2,3 are then syntactic sugar, but don’t exist on the level of the set theory itself...

Comment: @PrudiiArca In my understanding, the type of symbols $x_{i}$ exist for convenience, as numbers should not be introduced in the system of symbols. I guess we should have the type of expression like $\forall x, \forall y, \forall z$ and somehow relate the number of variables to $n$, if we want quantification on $n$.

Comment: Not an answer. In everyday mathematics proper formulations in words are just as rigorous as their formal expressions is set theory. They are usually much easier to understand, so I prefer them.

Comment: @ZiqiFan Sure. I was a hardliner on these kind of things as well, until I noted that it makes my life really hard. I mean what comes after $a,b,c,...,z$? And after Hebrew, Kyrillic, Chinese symbols? I figured it is way easier to keep track of what notion is *meta level* and what is *formal level*, than to trying hard to avoid this kind of problems of notation. But I do get your point and it is really important to think about these kind of things...

Comment: At a formal level, we would have a way in our language that allows the production of variable names and instead of $a,b,c,d,\ldots$ we might (for formal reasons) prefer $v,v',v'',v''',\ldots$ because "just append an apostroph" can be formalized when "just pick a new letter" cannot. Nevertheless, in the context of the OP, it might seem interesting to find a way to formalize (as in: get rid of ellipsis and underbrace) something like $$\forall n\underbrace{\exists x_1\cdots\exists x_n}_n\phi(n,x_1,\ldots, x_n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a way to talk about $n$-tuples without fixing a specific $n$, we can achieve this by shifting attention to **sequences as individual objects**. For example, in place of

> For every $n$, there are points $x_1,...,x_n$ such that [stuff]

we can write

> For every finite ordinal $x$ there is a function $T: x\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that [stuff]

(think of $x$ as $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and of $T(i)$ as $x_i$). Keep in mind that "finite ordinal" is something we can actually express in the language of set theory (e.g. as "hereditarily transitive set with no non-surjective self-injection").

---

Note that this idea also shows up in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem, a key piece of which is showing that the language of arithmetic can talk about finite sequences of natural numbers even though a priori it's only able to refer to individual natural numbers.

Comment: Good explanation. You are constructing a function to avoid the necessity to count symbols while keep the quantification on $n$. Thanks.